# UK dependant visa - what does "restricted work" mean?

Tags: visas, uk, work, work-permit

The BRP card of a person I'm interested in hiring states:

- Type of permit: Dependant leave to enter
- Remarks: Restricted work, no work as sportsperson

I'm hiring for an IT role, so the "no sportsperson" restriction doesn't apply, however whatt does "restricted work" mean in this context?

Here's the image of the card (with photo, name and number pixelised):
[image]

P.S. Of course, I will have the HR perform formal verification, however I want to establish if I should even start the hiring process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better suited for law stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

You can't check for that on the BRP itself, you can only check that status online (from [gov.uk wizard](https://www.gov.uk/legal-right-work-uk/y/from-somewhere-else/not-applied-to-the-eu-settlement-scheme/no/no/no/no/yes)) and, for that, they need to send you their [Share Code](https://www.gov.uk/view-prove-immigration-status)

---

As an aside, please know that this looks like a Tier 2 Skilled Worker BRP, of which the holder can't switch employer [without appropriate change of visa](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa)

> change jobs or employer unless you apply to update your visa

Comment: Thanks.  This is not a Tier 2 - it's clearly stated on the card - "Dependant"

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances, the only restriction is the professional sportsperson (including sports coach) prohibition under SW 36.3 of the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-skilled-worker). However, the share code is the most straightforward way to check a person's current immigration status and right to work, and is anyway required before you may hire a foreign worker.